# How to sort tableview stored datas using objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have loaded multiple datas into `tableview` like below diagrams. I need to create button first click to show all the data's `ascending order A` `to Z.` like below `figure (1)`

```
----------------------------------  
  A         14           30
----------------------------------  
  z         20           10
----------------------------------
```

Button second click to show all the data decending order `Z to A`. like below.

```
----------------------------------  
  Z        20           10
----------------------------------  
  A        14           30
----------------------------------
```

For some reason I have loaded multiple column values into separate `NSMutableArray for tableview`.

```
    NSDictionary *alertArray = [notificationdata objectForKey:@"response"];
    NSArray *sortedKeys = [[alertArray allKeys] 
sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    // Array_One
    NSMutableArray *one = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // Array_Two
    NSMutableArray *two = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

   for (keys in sortedKeys) {

        [one addObject:[alertArray objectForKey:keys][@"name"]];
        [two addObject:[alertArray objectForKey:keys][@"values"]];

    }
```

1. How to show descending order names?
2. How to show total reverse order no's (second column)?

Comment: Hope this link Help... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/SortingTableViews/SortingTableViews.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it . You can refer here.

Comment: explain your second question

Comment: Want to show all columns values reversely after button click.@Jincy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS..

```
NSDictionary *alertArray = [notificationdata objectForKey:@"response"];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [[alertArray allKeys] 
sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
// Array_One
NSMutableArray *one = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// Array_Two
NSMutableArray *two = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

one  = [[[alertArray allKeys] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@“name” ascending:NO]]] mutableCopy];
two = [[[alertArray allKeys] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@“value” ascending:YES]]] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Awesome Working now. Thank you but How to change numbers column ?@Jincy